# Problem with inserting row on mySQL using JDBC connection in android

Tags: android, mysql, jdbc

I followed this guy's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437118/insert-data-into-mysql-using-jdbc-through-android-facing-difficulty-in-this-err) on inserting.
Here's code for my `AsyncTask`

```
    private class sendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String z = "";

    boolean isSuccess = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Sending request...");
        progressDialog.show();

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            if (con == null) {
                z = "Please check your internet connection";
            } else {

                myArrayList.clear();

                String query = "insert into notifications (id, suggestion, type, isIgnored) values ('', '"+ sv.getQuery().toString()  +"', 'medicine', 'false')";

                Statement stmt1 = con.createStatement();

                stmt1.executeUpdate(query);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
            z = "Exceptions" + ex;
        }
        return z;
    }

    @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        if(!isSuccess && !z.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), z, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        progressDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

---

However it gives me this error message below, I was wondering why or how it was an error because my query was an insert not truncate. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,I would advice you to use **PreparedStatement** to set parameters to avoid **SQL Injection**

For your question,the reason is that `id` is type of `integer`,but you just passed `''` for it:

```
 String query = "insert into notifications (id, suggestion, type, isIgnored) values ('', '"+ sv.getQuery().toString()  +"', 'medicine', 'false')";
```

Two ways to solve it:
a. Pass an integer value for `id`
b. Make `id` as auto increment and remove `id` in the sql as below:

```
String query = "insert into notifications (suggestion, type, isIgnored) 
         values ('"+ sv.getQuery().toString()  +"', 'medicine', 'false')";
```

Comment: I see that you dropped the column `id`, so does it mean you have to define the id first right?

Comment: Maybe I could just retrieve the max value of id then increment it.

Comment: @Mr.Benbenbenbenben since you have set auto increment,just remove `id` in the sql and the database will create value for it

Comment: Yes I did! And it did work thanks, i have medium spec laptop so i was delayed

Comment: This answer could be improved by showing how a prepared statement can be used to solve this. Your answer mentions prepared statement, but then only provides the unsafe solution based on the current code of the OP.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes,the reason why I do not provide code of `prepared statement` is that I think if OP Google,he will find lots of related document,we had better not to provide everything for the OP,we need to learn how to search and solve problem by ourselves